# cursor.fetchall() function return an empty list - python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I tried to query some data from mysql database, but i couldn't fetch any data even though the data is indeed exist in the database and there is no error message whatsoever.

```
mysql_config={
    'user' : 'root',
    'password' : '*********',
    'host' : '*******',
    'database' : 'aa_dev',
    'port' : 3306
}

sql = 'SELECT idfi, aircraft, file_location FROM flights_info WHERE idfi =%s'
val = [('PK-YSG-23001',), ('PK-YSG-23002',), ('PK-YSG-23003',), ('PK-YSG-23004',)]

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
d = mycursor.fetchall()
mycursor.close()
print(d) #Output an empty list
```

Then I tried query only one data and get the result. But i still don't understand why can't i query the data in bulk?.

```
sql = 'SELECT idfi, aircraft, file_location FROM flights_info WHERE idfi =%s'
val = ('PK-YSG-23001',)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute(sql, val)
d = mycursor.fetchall()
mycursor.close()
print(d) #Output the data
```

Comment: Don't you rather want to execute _one_ query with `WHERE idfi IN ...`, then many separate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did below is instead of using the `executemany`, I modified the query to use an `IN` clause. This will allow us to fetch all the desired rows in one go.

```
sql = 'SELECT idfi, aircraft, file_location FROM flights_info WHERE idfi IN (%s)'

placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(val))
flattened_values = [item for sublist in val for item in sublist]

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute(sql % placeholders, flattened_values)
d = mycursor.fetchall()
mycursor.close()
print(d)
```